# How to fix 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)'

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

What I did (Structured Streaming)

```
> 1.) ./bin/pyspark
> 2.) spark
> 3.) static = spark.read.json("/data/activity-data/")
> 4.) dataSchema = static.schema
> 5.) streaming = spark.readStream.schema(dataSchema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)\
> 6.) .json("/data/activity-data")
> 7.) activityCounts = streaming.groupBy("gt").count()
```

Then I got this huge error.
Could you help me how to troubleshoot this?

ERRORs:

> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:121)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset.toDF(RelationalGroupedDataset.scala:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset.count(RelationalGroupedDataset.scala:237)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate keys, you will get this error.

You can also refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10925